# Секунды в таймере android

Tags: java, android

Я сделал с помощью `NumberPicker` таймер (секунды, минуты, часы). Минуты и часы выставить можно, но вот секунды нет (хотя сами секунды корректно работают, если выставить одна минута то будет 59 секунд). Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне это сделать. (при нажатии на кнопку у меня берется числа с `NumberPicker`)

```
mButtonSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int resH;
        int resS;
        if(numberPickerHor.getValue()!=0) {
            resH = numberPickerHor.getValue() * 60;
        }
        else {
            resH = 0;
        }
        if(numberPickersek.getValue()!=0){
            resS = numberPickersek.getValue()/60;
        }
        else {
            resS = 0;
        }
        int res =resH + numberPickerMin.getValue() + resS;
        String ress = String.valueOf(res);
        numberPickerHor.setValue(0);
        numberPickerMin.setValue(0);
        numberPickersek.setValue(0);
        long millisInput = Long.parseLong(ress) * 60000;
        setTime(millisInput);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов - использовать три виджета для часов, минут и секунд:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numpicker_hours"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </NumberPicker>

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numpicker_minutes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

    </NumberPicker>

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numpicker_seconds"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </NumberPicker>

</LinearLayout>
```

Второй вариант - можно взять [библиотеку](https://github.com/IvanKovac/TimePickerWithSeconds). [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57034554/9363441) указан кастомный `timePicker` не библиотека.