# Не добавляются секунды в таймере android

Tags: java, android

Всем привет, я делаю таймер с секундами, минутами, часами и использую `NumberPicker` (для секунд, минут и часов отдельный). Я могу выставить минуты и часы, но секунды не могу (когда выбираю любое значение, кроме 60, у меня таймер не меняется, а если 60 то все работает). Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему.
(значения выставляются при нажатии на кнопку)

```
mButtonSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int resH;
        int resS;

        if (numberPickerHor.getValue() != 0) {
            resH = numberPickerHor.getValue() * 60;
        } else {
            resH = 0;
        }
        if (numberPickersek.getValue() != 0) {
            resS = numberPickersek.getValue() / 60;
        } else {
            resS = 0;
        }

        int res = resH + numberPickerMin.getValue() + resS;
        String ress = String.valueOf(res);
        numberPickerHor.setValue(0);
        numberPickerMin.setValue(0);
        numberPickersek.setValue(0);
        long millisInput = Long.parseLong(ress) * 60000;

        setTime(millisInput);
    }
});
```

обновление времени и запись числа

```
private void updateCountDownText() {
    int hours = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 3600;
    int minutes = (int) ((mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 3600) / 60;
    int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;
    String timeLeftFormatted;
    if (hours > 0) {
        timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                "%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
    } else {
        timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
    }
    mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
}
```

Comment: Вы же все в целые минуты переводите. 59/60 = 0 целых. 60/60 = 1

Comment: И зачем переводить число в строку, потом обратно в число?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Секунды в таймере android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1126189/%d0%a1%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-android)